# Communicating between applications?

Tags: java, c++, python, communication

I am very new to programming, and have had no formal training in it before so please bear with me if this is a vague question.

I was just curious: how do different programs on the same computer communicate with each other? From my programming experience I believe it can be achieved by socket programming?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can rely on all different kind of inter process communication. (IPC). Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

On linux, dbus is used to make applications communicate together. Sockets are only one way to solve this provlem.

Answer (score 1):

Sockets, shared memory, events / signals, pipes, semaphores, message queues, mailslots. Just search the Internet for either.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WM_COPYDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows which is a really easy way to send data between different applications/processes.

And [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) is a list of other methods that work cross platforms, and with many different languages.